# how to work with css and html android

Tags: android, html, css

i have 1 html file and 1 css file 
css imported and linked in html it works in pc browser but not in android.
this is m code that i show m html

```
WebView wv;
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/barg.html");
```

What should I do to not show these figures instead of leaves

[image]

this is my html and css codes

```css
#leaves {position:relative;top:-50px;width:100%;text-align: right;}

#leaves i {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #309900, #005600);
    transform: skew(20deg);
    border-radius: 5% 40% 70%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #222;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: falling 5s 0s infinite;
}

#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n) { -webkit-animation: falling2 5s 0s infinite; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n) { -webkit-animation: falling3 5s 0s infinite; }

#leaves i:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 117px;
  right: 9px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 32px;
  transform: rotate(49deg);
  border-radius: 0% 15% 15% 0%;
  border-top: 1px solid #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  border-left: 0px solid #222;
  border-right: 1px solid #222;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,100,0,1), #005600);
  z-index: 1;
}

#leaves i:after {
  content: '';
  height: 125px;
  width: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.15), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(125deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 85px;
  border-radius:50%;
}


#leaves i:nth-of-type(n)    { height:23px; width:30px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(n):before { width:7px; height:5px; top:17px; right:1px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(n):after { width:2px; height:17px; left: 12px; top:0px; }

#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n+1)    { height:11px; width:16px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n+1):before { width:4px; height:3px; top:7px; right:0px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n+1):after { width:2px; height:6px; left: 5px; top:1px; }

#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n+2)  { height:17px; width:23px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n+2):before  { height:4px; width:4px; top:12px; right:1px; }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n+2):after  { height:10px; width:2px; top:1px; left:8px; }

#leaves i:nth-of-type(n)   { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.9s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 3.9s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(4n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 4.4s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(5n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;  }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(6n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(7n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 2.8s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(8n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(9n)  { -webkit-animation-delay: 3.3s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(10n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(11n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(12n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 4.1s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(13n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;  }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(14n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 4.7s;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(15n) { -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;  }

#leaves i:nth-of-type(n)    { background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #309900, #005600); }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(2n+2)  { background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #5e9900, #2b5600); }
#leaves i:nth-of-type(4n+1)  { background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #990, #564500); }

#leaves i:nth-of-type(n)    { opacity: .7;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n+1)  { opacity: .5;}
#leaves i:nth-of-type(3n+2)  { opacity: .3;}

#leaves i:nth-of-type(n)    {transform: rotate(180deg);}


#leaves i:nth-of-type(n) { -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;}

@-webkit-keyframes falling {
    
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(300,0,0)
            rotate(0deg);
    }
    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(-350px,700px,0)
            rotate(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes falling3 {
     0% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(0,0,0)
            rotate(-20deg);
    }
    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(-230px,640px,0)
            rotate(-70deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes falling2 {
     0% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(0,0,0)
            rotate(90deg);
    }
    
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:
            translate3d(-400px,680px,0)
            rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
@import url("barg2.css");
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="barg2.css" />
</style>
<div id="leaves">
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i> 
</div>
```

Comment: i want to show the leaves but it dos not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store CSS and html files in `assets` folder then this is what you have to do in the `Activity/Fragment`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 WebView WebViewWithCSS;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 WebViewWithCSS = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

 WebSettings webSetting = WebViewWithCSS.getSettings();
 webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 WebViewWithCSS.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 WebViewWithCSS.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 
 }

 private class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
 {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
 {
 return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
 }
 }
```

This works for me on `lollipop`
Hope this will help you somehow.